# ServiceStack.Text Serializer as default serializer/deserializer

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack-text

We are just starting to develop our new API client using ASP.net Web Api. Having found ServiceStack.Text i do not want to use JSON.NET serialization feature but replace them with ServiceStack.
How to set this serializer as default in Web Api?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` which uses ServiceStack's serializer/deserializer. Looks like some folks have already created formatter for this here: https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/wiki/Media-Type-Formatters

To make it as a default formatter, just insert this new custom formatter in the beginning of the global configuration's formatters list.